# Declaration rule in struct typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef, declaration

I'm reading 'The C Programming Language' and encountered a problem about typedef of **struct**. The code is like this:

```
typedef struct tnode *Treeptr;
typedef struct tnode { /* the tree node: */
    char *word; /* points to the text */
    int count; /* number of occurrences */
    struct tnode *left; /* left child */
    struct tnode *right; /* right child */
} Treenode;
```

By the time we write

```
typedef struct tnode *Treeptr;
```

tnode is still not declared yet, but we don't get any compilation error,
but when we change the statement above into:

```
typedef Treenode *Treeptr;
```

We get compilation error:

```
error: parse error before '*' token
warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

What causes the difference? Isn't "struct tnode" the same as "Treenode"?

Comment: You might find [Which part of the C standard allows this code to compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/which-part-of-the-c-standard-allows-this-code-to-compile) and [Does the C standard consider that there are one or two `struct uperms_entry` types in this header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697705/does-the-c-standard-consider-that-there-are-one-or-two-struct-uperms-entry-typ) as relevant, but they may be pitched at a level that is beyond where you're at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a type before it is defined.

With the `typedef struct tnode { ... } Treenode;` declaration, the type `Treenode` is not defined until the semi-colon is reached.

The situation with `typedef struct tnode *Treeptr;` is different.  This tells the compiler 'there is a structure type called `struct tnode`, and the type `Treeptr` is an alias for a pointer to a `struct tnode`'.  At the end of that declaration, `struct tnode` is an incomplete type.  You can create pointers to incomplete types but you cannot create variables of the incomplete type (so you could define `Treeptr ptr1;` or `struct tnode *ptr2;` and they are the same type, but you could not define `struct tnode node;`).

The body of the `struct tnode` could be written as:

```
typedef struct tnode
{
    char    *word;
    int      count;
    Treeptr  left;
    Treeptr  right;
} Treenode;
```

because `Treeptr` is a known alias for the type `struct tnode *` before the structure is defined.  You can't use `Treenode *left;` because `Treenode` is not a known alias until the final semi-colon is reached (roughly speaking).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `TreePtr`, you are not implementing the struct. That is known as a "*forward declaration*". Something like: "here we use this, but later I will explain it better". The implementation must appear later, only once, and that is what you find in the second `typedef`.

And `TreePtr` is not the same as the struct, because `TreePtr` will be in fact a new type that includes the fact of beeing a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, Fèlix, nice explanation. So you mean `struct undefined_struct *a;` is allowed, but we should implement the `undefined_struct` before we say `struct undefined_struct b", is that right? But what is the intention for this "_foward declaration_"?

Comment: Forward declarations, or incomplete types, can be helpful in two cases. It is possible to create mutually recursive structures, so that `struct a` contains a pointer to a `struct b` and `struct b` contains a pointer to a `struct a`. That's esoteric (but would be a real problem if forward declaration was not possible). The more coogent reason for incomplete types is that you can define the interface to a set of functions in terms of pointers to incomplete types and the public header never has to reveal what's inside the structures; they are an 'opaque type', and you're using information hiding.

Comment: You can do things like `struct undef a;`, `struct undef *b;`, etc. in any combination, as much as you need. You can include them inside another struct. But you _must_ declare the implementation of the struct once, where and when you prefer.

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué: I think it's only necessary to supply any definition for a struct in cases where one either dereferences it or tries to create a storage location of the structure type (rather than a pointer-to-structure type).  If a pointer types is never used as anything other than an opaque pointer type, there's no need to ever supply definition for the struct contents.

Answer (score 0):

A line `typedef struct tnode *Treeptr;` has implicit forward declaration of "tnode" struct. It's similar to:

```
typedef struct tnode Treenode;
typedef Treenode *Treeptr;

struct tnode { /* the tree node: */
    char *word; /* points to the text */
    int count; /* number of occurrences */
    struct tnode *left; /* left child */
    struct tnode *right; /* right child */
};
```