# LinkedList Struct Typedef in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I am try to build a basic linked list in C. I seem to get an error for this code:

```
typedef struct
{
    char letter;
    int number;
    list_t *next;
}list_t;

char letters[] = {"ABCDEFGH"};

list_t openGame, ruyLopez;
openGame.letter = letters[4];
openGame.number = 4;
openGame.next = &ruyLopez;


ruyLopez.letter = letters[5];
ruyLopez.number = 4;
ruyLopez.next = NULL;
```

It won't accept my definition in the struct:

```
list_t *next;
```

And for the same reason it won't accept:

```
openGame.next = &ruyLopez;
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. As to the actual problem: C is not C++. You have to refer to the structure type using the `struct` keyword until its definition is complete, i. e. `typedef struct list_t {  ... struct list_t *next; }`. But this has already been asked and answered here approx. 1038462475928745 times.

Comment: Oh, and `_t` types are reserved for use with POSIX, polluting that "namespace" results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3 [Referral Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225386/if-i-do-a-typedef-in-c-or-c-when-should-i-add-t-at-the-end-of-typedefed) for your point about `_t` suffixed type names.

Comment: @H2CO3: without a structure tag, that code won't even work in C++, will it?  It would have to be `typedef struct list_t { ...; list_t *next; } list_t;` to be valid (though the `typedef` and trailing `list_t` are redundant as well in C++; you could simply use `struct list_t { ...; list_t *next; };`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaration rule in struct typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303168/declaration-rule-in-struct-typedef).  I suspect there are other potential duplicates — possibly even better ones.

Comment: Another question on `_t` suffixes: [What does a type followed by `_t` (underscore-t) represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you are using `list_t *next` in your code, the compiler doesn't know what to do with `list_t`, as you haven't declared it yet. Try this:

```
typedef struct list {
    char letter;
    int number;
    struct list *next;
} list;
```

As H2CO3 pointed out in the comments, using `_t` as an identifier suffix is not a great idea, so don't use `list_t`.

Comment: third line should be struct list *next as per you code. Else we can do the following.typedef struct list list; struct list
{
    char letter;
    int number;
    list *next;
};

Comment: this naming trick solves many subtle self-reference problems. +1

Answer (score 1):

why did you make it hard on yourself just set `openGame` and `ruzeLopez` as pointers and you wont have to use the `&` (this is the usual way to use linked lists , just don't forget to use `->` to access members)

try this code instead :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct list
{
    char letter;
    int number;
    struct list *next;
}list;

main(void)
{
   char letters[] = "ABCDEFGH"; //what were the braces for ?
   list *openGame, *ruyLopez;
   openGame = ruyLopez = NULL;
   openGame = malloc(sizeof(list));
   ruyLopez = malloc(sizeof(list));

   openGame->letter = letters[4];
   openGame->number = 4;
   openGame->next = ruyLopez;

   ruyLopez->letter = letters[5];
   ruyLopez->number = 5;
   ruyLopez->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example without the risk of memory leaks from using malloc to create your structures.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _list
{
    char letter;
    int number;
    struct _list *next;
} list_type;

int main(void)
{
   char letters[] = "ABCDEFGH"; //what were the braces for ?
   list_type openGame, ruyLopez;
   openGame.letter = letters[4];
   openGame.number = 4;
   openGame.next = &ruyLopez;

   ruyLopez.letter = letters[5];
   ruyLopez.number = 5;
   ruyLopez.next = NULL;
}
```