# How to get the pointer of a struct inside a file

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, pointers, struct

I want to add ferries in a file as nodes and keep track of the previous and next pointers, with the purpose of creating a Circular Doubly Linked List. The name of the ship is written in the terminal as a parameter to the main function.

The code of the function for adding ferries:

```
int Register_ferry(char *f){
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("Ferries.txt","a+");
if(pFile!=0){
    FILE *dFile;
    dFile = fopen("Ferries.txt","r+");
    ferry *new_node=(ferry*)malloc(sizeof(ferry));
    ferry *new_node2=(ferry*)malloc(sizeof(ferry));
    fseek(pFile,0,SEEK_END);
    if(ftell(pFile)==0){
        new_node->fld=atoi(f);
            new_node->next=new_node;
        new_node->prev=new_node;
        printf("CURR: %p\n",new_node);
        printf("NEXT: %p\n",new_node->next);
        printf("PREV: %p\n",new_node->prev);
    }
    else if(ftell(pFile)==8){
        new_node->fld=atoi(f);
        fseek(dFile,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(new_node2,sizeof(new_node2),1,dFile);
        new_node->next=new_node2;
        new_node->prev=new_node2;
        new_node2->next=new_node;
        new_node2->prev=new_node;
        fwrite(new_node2, sizeof(new_node),1,dFile);
            printf("CURR: %p\n",new_node);
        printf("NEXT: %p\n",new_node->next);
        printf("PREV: %p\n",new_node->prev);    
    }
    else{   
        new_node->fld=atoi(f);
        fseek(dFile,-8,SEEK_END);
        fread(new_node2,sizeof(new_node2),1,dFile);
            new_node->prev=new_node2;
        fseek(dFile,0,SEEK_SET);
        fread(new_node2,sizeof(new_node2),1,dFile);
        new_node->next=new_node2;
        printf("CURR: %p\n",new_node);
        printf("NEXT: %p\n",new_node->next);
        printf("PREV: %p\n",new_node->prev);    
    }
    fwrite(new_node, sizeof(new_node), 1, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    free(new_node);
    free(new_node2);
}
return 0;}
```

The code of main:

```
 int main(int narg , char* argv[]){
 if (strcmp(argv[1], "R")==0)
 {  
    Register_ferry(argv[2]);
     }
 return 0;}
```

The struct for the ferries:

```
typedef struct ferry{
int fld;
struct ferry *next;
struct ferry *prev;
}ferry;
```

A photo of calling the program:
[image]

After some tries I realized that with the printf commands I wouldn't get the pointers of the nodes inside the file but the pointers of the nodes that I created with the function malloc. So my question is how am I supposed to get the pointers of the nodes inside the file to keep the Circular Doubly Linked List as it's supposed to be?

At last something minor but still important for some reason my function and the first if doesn't close with their corresponding '}'. However the terminal doesn't prompt any errors, so it's kinda weird.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. This means a short C code with a `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete example:

- Circular linked list in memory, flat list in file
- Only one struct to define data and links (pointers)
- Only one file (no headers or extra file needed)
- Don't write and read pointers, only data
- Calculate pointers during read
- Allocate memory for each node
- Free all claimed memory
- Added program parameter to just read all ferries and exit
- Added program parameter to allow saving the name, too

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ferry {
    int fld;
    char name[20];
    struct ferry *next;
    struct ferry *prev;
}ferry;

/* Full size used for malloc, without pointers for read/write */
#define FERRY_SIZE (sizeof(ferry))
#define FERRY_SIZE_WITHOUT_POINTERS (FERRY_SIZE - (sizeof(ferry*)*2))

#define FILE_DATA "Ferries.txt"

int write_ferries(ferry*first_node) {
    FILE *data_file;
    int count = 0;

    /* We will modify the pointer to loop over the linked list */
    ferry*node = first_node;

    data_file = fopen(FILE_DATA,"w");
    do {
        count++;
        fwrite(node, FERRY_SIZE_WITHOUT_POINTERS,1,data_file);
        node = node->next;
    } while(node != first_node);

    fclose(data_file);

    return count;
}

ferry* read_ferries() {
    FILE *data_file;
    int data_size;
    int num_nodes;
    ferry*first_node = NULL, *prev_node = NULL;
    int i;

    /* Get file size */
    /* If file does not exists or its size is zero, return NULL */
    data_file = fopen(FILE_DATA,"r+");
    if(data_file == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(data_file,0,SEEK_END);
    data_size = ftell(data_file);

    if(data_size == 0) {
        fclose(data_file);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Calculate num of nodes using file size and struct size */
    num_nodes = data_size / FERRY_SIZE_WITHOUT_POINTERS;
    fseek(data_file,0,SEEK_SET);

    /* Read all ferries and assign prev/next following file order */
    for(i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
        ferry *node = malloc(FERRY_SIZE);
        fread(node,FERRY_SIZE_WITHOUT_POINTERS,1,data_file);

        if(first_node == NULL) {
            first_node = node;
        }

        /* Assign prev/next using order in file */
        if(i > 0) {
            node->prev = prev_node;
            prev_node->next = node;
        }

        prev_node = node;
    }

    fclose(data_file);

    /* Link first and last nodes */
    prev_node->next = first_node;
    first_node->prev = prev_node;

    return first_node;
}

int free_all_nodes(ferry*first_node) {
    ferry*last_node = first_node->prev;
    ferry*node = first_node;

    do {
        node = node->next;
        free(node->prev);
    } while(node != last_node);
}

int Register_ferry(char *fld, char *name){
    /* Generate the new node */
    ferry *new_node = malloc(FERRY_SIZE);
    new_node->fld = atoi(fld);
    if(name != NULL && strlen(name) > 0) {
        strcpy(new_node->name, name);
    }

    /* Read all ferries, get the first */
    ferry*first_node = read_ferries();

    if(first_node == NULL) {
        /* If this is the first node */
        new_node->prev = new_node;
        new_node->next = new_node;
        write_ferries(new_node);

        printf("CURR: %p\n",new_node);
        printf("NEXT: %p\n",new_node->next);
        printf("PREV: %p\n",new_node->prev);

        /* Free single node memory */
        free(new_node);
    }
    else {
        printf("first_node CURR: %p\n",first_node);
        printf("first_node NEXT:%p\n",first_node->next);
        printf("first_node PREV:%p\n",first_node->prev);

        /* Link the new node */
        new_node->prev = first_node->prev;
        new_node->next = first_node;
 
        /* Update the first node to point its prev to the new one */
        first_node->prev = new_node;
 
        /* Update the last node to point its next to the new one */
        new_node->prev->next = new_node;

        /* Save the entire list */
        write_ferries(first_node);

        printf("CURR: %p\n",new_node);
        printf("NEXT: %p\n",new_node->next);
        printf("PREV: %p\n",new_node->prev);

        /* Free all allocated memory for nodes */
        free_all_nodes(first_node);
    }

    return 0;
}

int show_ferries(void) {
    ferry*first_node = read_ferries();
    ferry*node = first_node;
    int count = 0;

    if(first_node == NULL) {
        printf("No ferries yet.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        count++;
        printf("Ferry %d: %d - %s\n", count, node->fld, node->name);
        node = node->next;
    } while(node != first_node);

    free_all_nodes(first_node);

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "R") == 0) {  
        Register_ferry(argv[2], argv[3]);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "L") == 0) {  
        show_ferries();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really can't find the words to thank you for your effort to write a code from scratch to help a random person in the internet. I was really disgouraged for being stuck in this point for days, but after seeing your work I got pumped up to continue the exercise. Again thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I hope it helps better understand C and programming in general and encourages you keep going through this path.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to wrap your ferries data into a linked list struct. Then, you can save all your ferries in a flat file, and link them in another file, without having to save binary pointers into the file.

```c
typedef struct {
    int fld;
    char name[20];
    /* Some other fields */
} ferry;

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/18582440/2928168 :
typedef struct list {
    struct ferry *node;
    struct list *prev;
    struct list *next;
} list;
```

Then, you can use `fread` and `fwrite` to load and save the ferries data into a file by looping the list. The data regarding the order, will need to be saved using some other technique in a different file, or as a header of the first. For example, saving a triad of integers for each node, pointing to the **index** of the 3 nodes: current, previous and next.

Comment: The thing is I need to have the int fld(aka the name of the ship), the next and the prev pointers in the same struct called ferry(I forgot to write it on the post, just added it).

Comment: Pointers saved into a file are meaningless, so you cannot directly use `fread`/`fwrite` directly. `The thing is I need to have the int fld(aka the name of the ship), the next and the prev pointers in the same struct called ferry` Why?

Comment: Because that's what the exercise reads, but I think I can modify it a bit. Do you have any video to provide about your suggestion?

Comment: `Because that's what the exercise reads` Then, its forcing you to don't use `fread`/`fwtite` to read the binary data into the struct, or to use an intermediate struct which will need to be "translated" into the final `ferry` shape.

Comment: `Do you have any video to provide about your suggestion?` Sorry, I've never used videos to learn programming.

Comment: `or to use an intermediate struct which will need to be "translated" into the final ferry shape`, and how am I supposed to do that, do you have any helpful link for a similar post or site?(Btw thank you for the assistance you have provided this far)

Comment: `do you have any helpful link` Of course, you can use my answer for that. If you want, I can assist also on how to translate it into your original `ferry` struct.

Comment: Also, if `ferry` only contains an integer (`fld`), you don't really need to write the entire struct as binary data: you can just write that integer, followed by the index of the next and prev nodes.

Comment: `If you want, I can assist also on how to translate it into your original ferry struct` I would really appreciate it since I got kinda confused with the code in the link. `you can just write that integer, followed by the index of the next and prev nodesL` do you mean as a string?

Comment: `do you mean as a string?` Not necessarily, but you can replace `fread(new_node2,sizeof(new_node2),1,dFile);` with `fread(new_fld,sizeof(int),1,dFile);` and similar for the write.

Comment: `I got kinda confused with the code in the link` Which link?

Comment: `Which link?` this one stackoverflow.com/a/28919580/2928168 , `Not necessarily, but you can replace fread(new_node2,sizeof(new_node2),1,dFile); with fread(new_fld,sizeof(int),1,dFile); and similar for the write`, I have to add something more in the struct, so no it's not possible, but I thought what if I create an array of struct ferries, and each time I run the program to read the content of the file inside the array, make the changes and the write it on the file. Is it possible? I am currently trying with this method, but I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: It can work, but if the struct has pointers, they will be meaningless on write and useless on read.

Comment: `It can work, but if the struct has pointers, they will be meaningless on write and useless on read`, sadly yes it's gonna have a pointer of another struct, sooo any ideas what the heck to do?

Comment: Added new answer with full working example.