# How do I use a typedef struct with that same struct in the inside?

Tags: c, struct

I want to avoid having to write `struct` before every time I create a new struct variable, so I'm `typedef`ing it.

The following doesn't work:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    Node *next;
} Node;
```

This does though:

```
struct Node {  
  int date; 
  struct Node *next;  
};
```

How do I use a typedef struct in C? I keep getting this error with the above one:

```
error: unknown type name 'Node'
            Node *next;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [self referential struct definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition)

Comment: Actually a duplicate of [Declaration rule in struct typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303168/declaration-rule-in-struct-typedef).

Answer (score 2):

The typedef doesn't take effect until the whole typedef statement has ended.

I haven't tried it, but you *might* be able to typedef against a forward reference:

```
typedef struct Node_struct Node;
struct Node_struct {  
  int date; 
  Node *next;  
};
```

You can certainly do it the other way around

```
struct Node_struct {  
  int date; 
  struct Node_struct *next;  
};
typedef struct Node_struct Node;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can typedef `struct Node` to `Node`, but the typedef isn't completed when you reference `Node`. Therefore you must type `struct Node`. My previous edit was incorrect because the struct didn't have a name, which will cause problems with pointers.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```