# Declaration of struct twice

Tags: c, struct

I have come across code like this multiple times and can't seem to grasp the idea or necessity behind it. I am referring to why does some code declare a struct of said name then they use typedef then declare the struct again and only add the contents of the struct? An example is below:

```
struct foo;
typedef struct foo *foobar;

struct foo {
    void *data;
    foobar example[];
};
```

Isn't this declaration slightly unnecessary, couldn't it be as follows?

```
typedef struct foo *foobar;

struct foo {
    void *data;
    foobar example[];
};
```

Comment: Did you try compiling either or both of your alternatives? Did they both work?

Comment: @Secernere I don't believe you. Both of your alternatives are errors.

Comment: Whats wrong with the first alternative? The second one is an error compiler read an alternative from the header file when I compiled.

Comment: @Secernere They both try to use `foobar` as a type before it is defined.

Comment: OK, that last edit completely changed your question, invalidating all answers. Sigh.

Comment: Note [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — succinctly, the answer is no unless it is a function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one time the long-winded notation matters is where the sequence is inside a function and there's a type `struct foo` defined outside the function too.  Then the plain `struct foo;` line shadows the out-of-function definition.  If you don't include that line, you can end up with incompatible pointer types, both called `foobar`, in structures that look the same, leading to horrible confusion.  (See also [Which part of the C standard allows this code to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200096/) and [Does the C standard consider that there are one or two 'struct uperms_entry' types in this header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697705/) for some more examples.)

What?  You're confused by what I said?  OK; here comes an example.  Note this is contrived; it is bad style to redefine a structure type inside a function (and the example of the problem depends on you doing so).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo;      // This line is optional; it is harmless if omitted
typedef struct foo *foobar;

struct foo
{
    void *data;
    foobar example[];  // Flexible array member; array of pointers.
};

extern void some_function(void);

void some_function(void)
{
    struct foo;     // This line is crucial!
    typedef struct foo *foobar;

    struct foo
    {
        foobar *array[3];
        void *pointer;
    };
    foobar x = calloc(sizeof(*x), 1);
    foobar y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
    y->array[0] = x->array[1];
    y->array[1] = x->array[2];
    y->array[2] = x->array[0];
    y->pointer  = x->array[1];

    free(x);
    free(y);
}
```

With the `struct foo;` line in the function, the code compiles cleanly:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -c st97.c
$
```

The `struct foo;` line inside the function says "forget about any previous `struct foo` type; there's a new one in this scope".  The forgetfulness only lasts for the scope, of course.

With the `struct foo;` line commented out in the function, the code fails to compile noisily:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -c st97.c
st97.c: In function ‘some_function’:
st97.c:28:6: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[0] = x->array[1];
      ^~
st97.c:28:20: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[0] = x->array[1];
                    ^~
st97.c:29:6: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[1] = x->array[2];
      ^~
st97.c:29:20: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[1] = x->array[2];
                    ^~
st97.c:30:6: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[2] = x->array[0];
      ^~
st97.c:30:20: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->array[2] = x->array[0];
                    ^~
st97.c:31:6: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘pointer’
     y->pointer  = x->array[1];
      ^~
st97.c:31:20: error: ‘struct foo’ has no member named ‘array’
     y->pointer  = x->array[1];
                    ^~
$
```

At the point when the type `foobar` is defined inside the function, the name `struct foo` refers to the type defined outside the function, so the structure contains an array of pointers to pointers to the external `struct foo`, and that structure has members `data` and `example` and not members `array` and `pointer`.

As I said, this is appalling style.  So, you say "what about if I use `struct foo` inside the structure definition in the function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo;
typedef struct foo *foobar;

struct foo
{
    void *data;
    foobar example[];  // Flexible array member; array of pointers.
};

extern void some_function(void);

void some_function(void)
{
    //struct foo;
    typedef struct foo *foobar;

    struct foo
    {
        struct foo *array[3];
        void *pointer;
    };
    foobar x = calloc(sizeof(*x), 1);
    foobar y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
    y->array[0] = x->array[1];
    y->array[1] = x->array[2];
    y->array[2] = x->array[0];
    y->pointer  = x->array[1];

    free(x);
    free(y);
}
```

This is still a problem.  The internal `struct foo` is not complete until the `}`, so the `struct foo *example[3]` still refers to the external `struct foo` — and you get the same error messages.

The short moral is "do not redefine a structure type inside a function".

If you must do so, note that it can only really be used in the function; it is hard to pass it to other functions — not quite impossible, but you really have to know what you're doing.

And the longer moral is "occasionally, under dubious circumstances, the `struct foo;` line on its own can be crucial".

Note that even if the structure body definitions are actually the same, technically, they're different types (both called `struct foo` though).  This is confusing to everyone — don't do it, please!  Actually, let's make that more imperative:

> ***Don't do it!***

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a typedef before you can reference it.  (Additionally, there is a school of thought that discourages the use of pointer typedefs, but that is strictly a convention.)

Typically one will see a "forward" typedef for a struct in cases where the struct itself contains pointers to other instances of itself, or more generally sets of structs that mutually reference each other.  For example:

```
typedef struct foo_s foo;
struct foo_s {
    int val;
    foo *next;
};
```

You could, of course, always use the structure tag in the structure definition, i.e. `struct foo_s`, but if the desire is to use the typedef `foo` consistently, then it needs to be defined before the structure is defined.

Comment: Why "more commonly"? OP's question is about exactly this case: A struct containing pointers to itself.

Comment: @melpomene ok, I reworded it.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Your first suggestion,

```
struct foo {
    void *data;
    foobar example[];
};

typedef struct foo *foobar;
```

yields:

```
error: unknown type name 'foobar'
     foobar example[];
     ^
```

and your second,

```
typedef struct foo {
    void *data;
    foobar example[];
} *foobar;
```

yields:

```
error: unknown type name 'foobar'
     foobar example[];
     ^
```

You have to declare before you define. The original way works because both

```
struct foo;
```

and

```
typedef struct foo *foobar;
```

are declarations that are not definitions. Such "non-definitional declarations" need to be employed to make mutually-recursive name references work.

As pointed out in the comments (thanks @melpomene) the `struct foo;` declaration is actually not required.

Comment: The original version works because `typedef struct foo *foobar;` appears before the struct definition. The `struct foo;` line is actually redundant.